# Counting rows that have same values in spcific columns in csv

Tags: python

I have a csv that i want to count how many rows that match specific columns, what would be the best way to do this? So for example if this was the csv:

```
         fruit  days characteristic1 characteristic2
0        apple     1             red           sweet
1       orange     2           round           sweet
2    pineapple     5         prickly           sweet
3        apple     4          yellow           sweet
```

the output i would want would be

1 apple: red,sweet

Comment: Please post the code you have thus far. People are quite willing to help you with a problem, but are rarely doing *the work for you*.

Comment: The "best way" is to use pandas. Try it out, there are loads of tutorials online. Please post a question if you get stuck

Comment: Ok so i think i was able to get what i needed with pandas  `` fruit_characteristics = df.pivot_table(index=['fruit','characteristic1', 'characteristic2'], aggfunc='size').to_frame()
``  how would combine the count if lets say a row Grapefruit **char1** bitter **char2** yellow and another row is  **char1** yellow **char2** bitter  they are essentially the same but the values are in different columns

Answer (score -1):

A csv is a file with values that are separated by commas. I would recommend turning this into a `.txt` file and using this same format. Then establish consistent spacing throughout your file (using tab for example). So that when you loop through each line it knows where the actual information is. Then when you what info is in what column you print those specific values.

```
      # Use a tab in between each column
      fruit    days    charac1    charac2
 0    apple1    1    red    sweet
 1    orange    2    round    sweet
 2    pineapple    5    prickly    sweet
 3    apple    4    yellow    sweet
```

This is just to get you started.